# ¿Es posible eliminar el efecto hover de un mat-expansion-panel de Angular Material con Css?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-expansion

Tengo el siguiente componente, y cambie el color del header Y el texto a morado como se muestra en la imagen

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title class="text">
          This is the expansion title
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
          This is a summary of the content
        </mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
   top: 50px;
   left: 200px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 1600px;
  }


  .mat-expansion-panel-header{
    background-color: blueviolet;

  }

  .text{
    color: white;
  }

  .mat-expansion-panel-header:hover{
    background-color: blueviolet !important;

  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando se expande y paso el cursor por debajo del header, desaparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando vuelvo a pasar el cursor encima del header ya aparece de nuevo, y lo que quiero hacer es quitar ese efecto o hacer que no desaparezca, que aunque pase el cursor o no encima del header, siempre este visible, como le podria hacer?, seria con Css? O que otro componente de Angular puedo ocupar que no le suceda ese efecto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega una clase en css donde el hover sea igual al color del fondo.

Comment: Tengo eso, como seria el hover entonces .mat-expansion-panel-header:hover{
    background-color: blueviolet !important;

  }

Comment: intenteé con :hover{  background-color: blueviolet !important; } pero no funciona